# Remove Picasso showing blue / green / red triangle at top of corner

Tags: android, picasso

I want to remove blue / green / red triangle showing at the top of corner using **Picasso**

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Code:

```
Picasso.get()
.load(img.getImage()).
placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
.into(holder.imageView);
```

Tried:

```
.setIndicatorsEnabled(false)
```

Getting:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setIndicatorsEnabled(boolean)'
```

Comment: why this question has been downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `setIndicatorsEnabled`, you need to assume Picasso as a singleton instance.

```
Picasso mPicasso = Picasso.get();
mPicasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false);
mPicasso.load(img.getImage()).
placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery)
.into(holder.imageView);
```

And to remove blue/green/red triangle showing at the top of the corner  you need to set

`setIndicatorsEnabled` to false

```
.setIndicatorsEnabled(false)
```

Hope this will help you.